# Joining 4 Tables in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

Individual Table:
IndividualID
Age
Name
Sex

Whistle Table
WhistleID
BoutID
IndividualID
ContorFilePath

Bout:
BoutID
FilePath
Length
Offset
Activity

Recording:
RecordingID
RecordingName
Date
Depth
Location
Weather

These are the tables. I want to select the BoutID when the user enters a Specific Name (From individual Table) and Date (From recordingTable) but this involves joining 4 tables? I've only ever joined two tables so im unsure of the syntax required?

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the query design editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access multiple joins require parentheses -- which are not generally recommended when using other databases.  Also, the join keyword is `INNER JOIN` rather than just `JOIN`.

So the structure for 4 tables would look like:

```
select . . .
from (((a inner join
        b
        on . . .
       ) inner join
       c
       on . . .
      ) inner join
      d
      on . . .
```

Comment: Many thanks, I thought it could be done like this but wanted to check!

Comment: @AdamHindle When this helped you, you could mark this as the right answer!